# Street address fields translations issue

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, translate

This is my method from the core of magento:

```
\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger::getMultilineFieldConfig
```

and this is the code:

```
....
 $line = [
                'label' => __("%1: Line %2", $attributeConfig['label'], $lineIndex + 1),
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
....
```

I would like to translate this `%1: Line %2`, which currently generates this:

```
Street Line 1, Street Line 2 and Street Line 3
```

into this:

```
Straat, Huisnummer, Toevoeging
```

But it doesn't work. I've tried this:

```
"%1: Line 1","%1"
"%1: Line 2","Huisnummer"
"%1: Line 3","Toevoeging"
```

But no luck :) Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem and did a little trick to make translations work.
You need to patch the file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/AttributeMerger.php` around line 292 to become:

from: `'label' => __("%1: Line %2", $attributeConfig['label'], $lineIndex + 1),`

to: `'label' => __($attributeConfig['label'] . ": Line " . $lineIndex + 1),`

Make sure you do it with a patch.

And apply translations that you need in your CSV file:

```
"Street Address: Line 1","Staatnaam"
"Street Address: Line 1","Huisnummer"
"Street Address: Line 3","Toevoeging"
```

To translate Magento expects `%1: Line %2` in CSV, and in case you asked it is not a match for `Street Address: Line 1`, `Street Address: Line 2`, etc. With the patch/modification in core file, the change is not a big deal so you are safe to do it.

I know that the question is > 1 year old and hope it helps to you or anybody else that might encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, I can't seem to find where I can change the translation for these fields. I hope someone will have a solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/205334)